# EditText addTextChangedListener is not effecting when i used setOnTouchListener with the same editText?

Tags: android

i want to use Edit Text to input Date from user. 
So i used setOnTouchListener , like below

```
editText_DOB.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if (v == editText_DOB)
showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
return false;
}
});
```

And at the same time I used  Validate on Edit Text using add Text ChangedListener And on Submit Button click , and showing errors on text changed listener,

```
if (editText_DOB.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
editText_DOB.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>DOB is required!</font>"));
```

My Question is , when i pressed Submit Button first, it show RED mark on Edit Text, it is OK. But when i click on Edit Text , Date Piker dialog appears and set date value to Edit Text. But Red mark still showing and not effected on text changed .

Answer (score 2):

```
editText_DOB.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 if (v == editText_DOB)
  {
   editText_DOB.setError("");
   showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);}
   return false;
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set EditText setError(null) before show date dialog :

```
editText_DOB.setError(null);
showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

I add set error as null below where i was set Text Date value in Edit Text.

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

        editText_DOB.setText(date_selected);
        editText_DOB.setError(null);
    }
```